Sql join with like condition not working for non exact matches
I am trying to join my expenses table with like query to categorize them into defined categories. I am trying if my expenses table even have a mention of a full keyword from lookup table, it should categorize them. Example, it does not show 'fine Esso brampton' categorized as 'Gas'. But the like join only works for exact match. Please suggest what's the issue here:
SELECT expenses.Description, expenses.Amount, COALESCE(lookup.Category, 'Others') as Category
FROM expenses
LEFT join lookup ON lookup.Description LIKE CONCAT('%', expenses.Description,'%')




Isn't your LIKE condition backwards?

It's other way around in LIKE.  And for exact match it does not matter.

It should be 'fine Esso brampton' LIKE '%Esso%'

@PM77-1 I tried the following query as you suggested, still gives me Category 'Others' for 'fine Esso brampton':
FROM expenses
LEFT join lookup ON CONCAT('%', expenses.Description,'%') LIKE lookup.Description```

@Евгений-Кудик comment resolved it for me, I think you meant the same. Thanks

it seems to me or need to swap fields like
SELECT expenses.Description, expenses.Amount, COALESCE(lookup.Category, 'Others') as Category
FROM expenses
LEFT join lookup ON expenses.Description LIKE CONCAT('%', lookup.Description ,'%')

